# Int from byte representation in vector c++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, stdvector

I have a `vector<int>` of length n which contains only 0 and 1's. For example we can have the following vector of length 10:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Now I use the number represented by that vector to access a location in an array with 2^n entries (so in this case an array of 2^10 = 1024). I'm not sure how I can obtain one integer from the byte representation stored in this `vector<int>`.

Comment: What about std::bitset instead of vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run through the vector and collect powers of 2.

It depends on which end of the vector you want as most significant digit but e.g.

```
auto to_int( const vector<int>& digits )
    -> int
{
    int result = 0;
    for( int const digit : digits )
    {
        result += 2*result + digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or the other way,

```
auto to_int( const vector<int>& digits )
    -> int
{
    int result = 0;
    for( int i = (int)digits.size();  i --> 0; )
    {
        result += 2*result + digits[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer: code not reviewed by compiler.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `auto -> int` over plain `int` return type?

Comment: Many. Read up on it. :)

Comment: Maybe it would make an ineresting question. I don't consider myself an ignorant, but I haven't seen such usage when the type is explicit. Oh, and the great `-->` operator. I start to think you like to obfuscate syntax =P

Comment: @Cheers Way too complicated, just using `std::bitset` is sufficient.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks a lot, will accept as soon as it lets me. I understand that the first solution would be taking MSB from the left?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: [`std::bitset` lacks a suitable constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) to take integer digit values.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf last question, would I simply call this function like this : to_int(my_vector); ?

Comment: Yes, the modern (trailing return type) function declaration syntax doesn't change the way you use functions.

Answer (score 0):

use a std::bitset (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) which has a to_ulong() method

Answer (score 0):

A simply way using a `for` loop:

```
size_t val{0};
for (const auto i : vec)
    val = (val << 1) + i;
```

Comment: You probably meant `<<`, not `<`. It's generally a good idea to leave that optimization to the compiler, just writing `2*`. ;-)

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. Since we're constructing a byte from a bit pattern I find the shift more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int integer=0;
int c=0;
for(int i : intVector){
    integer+=i<<c;
    c++;
}
return integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the `std::vector` and use `std::bitset`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

template <typename IterType>
unsigned long getValue(IterType i1, IterType i2)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long)> b;
    std::for_each(i1, i2, [&](auto n) { b.set(i++, n);});
    return b.to_ulong();
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
    auto val = getValue(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
    std::cout << val << "\n";;  
    auto val2 = getValue(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << val2;  
}
```

Note that depending on which bit is the most significant bit, you supply the iterators accordingly.  For right-to-left, supply reverse iterators, otherwise supply forward iterators.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/1SuETi)